# Inserting into a list at an index

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am trying to insert a value into a "register" with SML. If the list (or register) is not defined at that index I need to make a list of 0s up until that index. I have attempted the following but cannot get it to work.

```
fun storeInReg [] valIns idx = 
  if idx = 0 then
    [valIns]
  else 
    0::storeInReg( [] valIns (idx-1))
| storeInReg head::tail valIns idx =
    if idx = 0 then 
      valIns::t
    else
      head::storeInReg(tail valIns (idx-1));
```

idx can only be a value between 0 and 9.
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic logic is okay. Just a few syntax errors:

1) `t` is unbound in `valIns::t`. You doubtless meant `tail`

2) You start by defining `fun storeInReg [] valIns idx` (the curried form of multi-variable functions common in SML) but then later use things like

```
storeInReg( [] valIns (idx-1))
```

where you seem to be trying to pass (an ill-formed) tuple to `storeInReg`. Instead you need

```
(storeInReg [] valIns (idx-1))
```

3) Function evaluation has the highest possible precedence in SML, thus the expression

```
storeInReg head::tail valIns idx
```

tries to apply the function to `head` and then concatenate the result to `tail valIns idx` -- which makes no sense. Instead you need

```
storeInReg (head::tail) valIns idx
```

Making these changes yields:

```
fun storeInReg [] valIns idx = 
  if idx = 0 then
    [valIns]
  else 
    0::(storeInReg [] valIns (idx-1))
| storeInReg (head::tail) valIns idx =
    if idx = 0 then 
      valIns::tail
    else
      head::(storeInReg tail valIns (idx-1));
```

It now works as expected:

```
- val r = storeInReg [] 5 9;
val r = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5] : int list
- storeInReg r 4 3;
val it = [0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,5] : int list
```